# How to collect information of every single CPU?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

If my PC has four CPUs(CPU0, CPU1, CPU2, CPU3), how can I know the number of running processes and the queue length of each CPU?

Answer (score 2):

In **/proc/sched_debug** you can see for each cpu:

- the number of running processes (**cfs_rq[0].nr_running**)
- the runnable processes (**runnable tasks**)

  ```
  cat /proc/sched_debug | less
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Look at **/sys/kernel/debug/sched/debug** file. Same as **/proc/sched_debug** from the previous answer. In my case in proc folder there was no sched_debug, but found the same content in the mentioned path.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the **/proc/stat** and **/proc/schedstat** files.
There is also information per process in **/proc/<pid>/stat**.

- Information on /proc/stat is here:  http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.3/fs/proc/stat.c
- Information on /proc/schedstat :    http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.3/kernel/sched/stats.c